# Getting monitor URL in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, onedrive

Copying a file on a personal OneDrive using Microsoft Graph. The code below works fine and the file gets copied. According to documentation, the operation should return monitor url since copying is async operation.

**How can I get the monitor URL? PostAsync in the code below returns null.**

```
        var destination = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemReference
        {
            Path = $"/drive/root:{toPath}"
        };

        // result is null, where is monitor URL?
        var result = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fromFilePath)
            .Copy(null, destination)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
```

Comment: The API returns a `202 Accepted` with a `Location` header and an empty body for this scenario. It looks like the SDK isn't exposing that to you - it might be an idea to follow up over at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/226

Comment: Thanks for the link, Brad!